# OSX - How to identify window under cursor in all spaces including fullscreen

Tags: cocoa, fullscreen, nswindow

I'm using Window Services' `CGWindowListCreate` and `CGWindowListCreateDescriptionFromArray` to get window information. When getting `kCGWindowBounds` in a regular Space everything works fine (I'm drawing borders around the frontmost window on the 0th level). However, when I use the same method while on a fullscreen application's Space, I get nonsense bounds: (0, 855, 480, 1).

I wouldn't care much about this if there was an easy way to tell if I'm currently at a fullscreen app's Space, because then I'd just draw a border around the screen (well... it *would* depend if the menu bar is showing...).

Is this a bug, or is there a reason for this behavior?

**EDIT:**
Figured out my problem. It's a bigger issue than I would have liked. The thing is the API goes through ALL NSWindows, even the ones that aren't, well, normal windows. Chrome's loading bar on the bottom is a window by itself, for example, and Mail also has some window on the top of the app. This is a problem because I have no way to differentiate the window that looks to be frontmost.

For my app, I would like to capture a specific window to intercept mouse events in it. I would have liked to be able to have the user press a hotkey and then click on the desired window to select, but there is no API to get the window under the cursor. I have no clue how to proceed.

**Edit 2:**
To better help people find a useful answer, changed title from: "Quartz Window Services returning wrong window bounds for fullscreen apps"

Answer (score 0):

Have you got these methods defined for the window delegate?

```
- (NSSize)window:(NSWindow *)window willUseFullScreenContentSize:(NSSize)proposedSize
{
    NSRect mainDisplayRect = [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame];
    CGSize cgScreenSize = CGSizeMake(mainDisplayRect.size.width, mainDisplayRect.size.height);

    return cgScreenSize;
}

- (void)windowWillEnterFullScreen:(NSNotification *)notification
{

}

- (void)windowDidEnterFullScreen:(NSNotification *)notification
{

}

- (void)windowWillExitFullScreen:(NSNotification *)notification
{

}
```

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear, but I'm interested in windows of apps other than mine.

Comment: I haven't done this before, but maybe you should be asking for the window frame, not the bounds: NSRect windowRect = [aWindowID frame];

Answer (score 0):

I proceeded by going through the description dictionaries and checking if the current cursor position was inside the bounds of the windows. The first window to satisfy this would be the window right under the cursor, which is exactly what I needed.

Separately, to find the current top-most window, I used the iChat Apple example of the Accessibility API to register `ApplicationActivatedNotification` and `MainWindowDidChangeNotification`s. Both notifications combined would let me keep track of the main window of the active app (top-most). To get the bounds in this case, I just got the main window's position and size using the Accessibility API.